# Replace empty dicts in nested dicts

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary whose structure looks like this

```
{"a":{},"b":{"c":{}}}
```

Every key is a string and every value is a dict.
I need to replace every empty dict with `""`. How would I go about this?

Comment: Check values for a empty dict recursively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
def foo(the_dict):
    if the_dict == {}:
        return ""
    return {k : foo(v) for k,v in the_dict.items()}
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/CornyPeachpuffHack)

Comment: This assumes that all values are dictionaries, though. That's true for the sample dict in the question, but I suspect there might be other kinds of values is the actual input. It's simple to solve by adding `if not isinstance(the_dict, dict): return the_dict`

Comment: **Every key is a string and every value is a dict** @HåkenLid, I just kept it simple.

Answer (score 3):

Checking values for an empty dict recursively, and replacing with empty string if so.

```
>>> d = {"a":{},"b":{"c":{}}}
>>> def replace_empty(d):
...     for k, v in d.items():
...         if not bool(v):
...             d[k] = ""
...         else:
...             d[k] = replace_empty(v)
...     return d
>>> replace_empty(d)
{'a': '', 'b': {'c': ''}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the dictionary be `cd` then:-

```
>>> def foo(cd):
...     for x in cd:
...             if cd[x] == {}:
...                     cd[x] = ""
...             else: foo(cd[x])
...     return cd

>>> cd = {"a":{},"b":{"c":{}}}
>>> foo(cd)
{'a': '', 'b': {'c': ''}}
```

The thinking process goes like this:-

Firstly make a processor which will process your dictionary and replace all empty dictionaries with empty strings. Then just give all the dictionaries the opportunity to meet that processor.